# Traefik container fails with file rules

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I am trying to run a simple Traefik container with a yml configuration to make some tests, but I cannot start it.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.0.1
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${PWD}/traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
    command:
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:7000
      # - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG
    ports:
      - "9999:8080"
      - "7000:80"
```

**traefik.yml**

```
http:
  routers:
    to-reg:
      entryPoints:
        - web
      rule: Path(`/reg`)
      service: srv-reg

  services:
    srv-reg:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: http://192.168.226.141:9900
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I get:

```
proxy_1  | 2019/10/02 11:29:33 command traefik error: invalid node traefik: no child
```

I am pretty sure I am doing a silly error, but I cannot understand which from the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found my error (and as expected is a silly one): I had not understood the distinction between static and dynamic configuration and I was mounting the dynamic one where traefik expects the static. This cause that strange error.

Once I renamed `traefik.yml` in `dyn-traefik.yml` I have been able to mount in `/etc/traefik` and start the proxy with expected routing configuration.

Comment: I got this error when accidentally upgrading from 1.x to 2.0.